# Flutter - Set Text in new line

Tags: flutter, text, frameworks

I am new in flutter , and now I'm working on design an application

but in this part of project I want to set price in new line below the title , I have looking for similar question here but I can't solve it

Here is code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Card(
  child: Hero(
      tag: prod_name,
      child: Material(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {},
          child: GridTile(
              footer: Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Text(
                    prod_name,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 12),
                  ),
                  title: Text("\$$prod_old_price"),
                  subtitle: Text(
                    "\$$prod_price",
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              child: Image.asset(
                prod_pic,
                fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
              )),
        ),
      )),
);
```

}

Comment: Isn't the subtitle on a new line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Mehrdad Hosseini, You have to take one column with two children for subtitle of card and give the two text widgets as two children. Please go through the below changes in your code.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Hero(
          tag: prod_name,
          child: Material(
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {},
              child: GridTile(
                  footer: Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        prod_name,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 12),
                      ),
                      subtitle: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text("\$$prod_old_price"),
                          Text(
                            "\$$prod_price",
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    prod_pic,
                    fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                  )),
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

[image]

```
ListTile(
 title: Text('$prod_name'),
 subtitle: Text(
  '''\$$old_price\n\$$prod_price''',
  style: TextStyle(
   fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
  ),
 ),
)
```

Comment: @MehrdadHosseini You can mark the answer as correct so people coming here know the question has a correct answer